# How to display City, State after selection?

Tags: algolia

I'm using the City search from the example https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html#city-search

When you made selection, it only displays the City. How can I display it as City, State?

```
<input type="search" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="In which city do you live?" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.17.1"></script>
<script>
(function() {
  var placesAutocomplete = places({
    appId: '<YOUR_PLACES_APP_ID>',
    apiKey: '<YOUR_PLACES_API_KEY>',
    container: document.querySelector('#city'),
    templates: {
      value: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion.name;
      }
    }
  }).configure({
    type: 'city',
    aroundLatLngViaIP: false,
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of linking to an external resource could you provide us with a minimum working example?

Comment: Please always provide the code you ask for at your question. Just copy and paste it here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example